# ImageMagick : make images of different sizes float to top

Tags: imagemagick

I have 7 images that I'm trying to concatenate in a 4x2 tiling. They are all the same width, and have roughly the same height, except one that is about twice higher than the others (4th image). I'm trying to make them tile so that the 4th image covers the space of 2 images in the tiling, but what I get is this :

[image: Get rid of the whitespace]

How can I get rid of the whitespace, and make all the images "float" to the top? I don't mind if the bottom images aren't aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would favour `convert` over `montage` for this. All you need to know is that `-append` appends the second picture *below* the first and that `+append` appends the second picture to the *right* of the first.

So, I effectively put `5` below `1` to make a single taller picture, `6` below `2` to make another single taller picture and then `6 & 2` to the right of `1 & 5` etc and then finally stuff `4` at the end on the right:

```
convert -background none           \
 \( 1.png 5.png -append \)         \
 \( 2.png 6.png -append \) +append \
 \( 3.png 7.png -append \) +append \
 4.png +append result.png
```

[image]

If you want spacers between your images you can add them in like this:

```
convert -background none \( 1.png 5.png -append \) xc:none[10x10] +append \( 2.png 6.png -append \) xc:none[10x10] +append \( 3.png 7.png -append \) xc:none[10x10] +append 4.png +append result.png
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the detailed explanation and illustrations!

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck with your project.